# Updating a file with <fstream> library (overwriting just a specific section)

Tags: c++, file, fstream, overwrite

I want to ask if there is any way to update say a text file with a content of "ooooo" to 
"ooXXo" using the fstream library. I know there is a way with cstdio but I don't want to use that one because of unsupported exception handling... Also, I don't want to read the file to memory, update the section I want and then write everything to a clean file...basically I'm looking for a way to do this with fstream:

```
/* fseek example */
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  FILE * pFile;
  pFile = fopen ( "example.txt" , "w" );
  fputs ( "This is an apple." , pFile );
  fseek ( pFile , 9 , SEEK_SET );
  fputs ( " sam" , pFile );
  fclose ( pFile );
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <fstream>

int main (){
  std::fstream pFile("example.txt");
  pFile << "This is an apple.";
  pFile.seekp(9);
  pFile << "sam";
  pFile.close();
  return 0;
}
```

fstream by default opens the file for both reading and writing. There's a second argument with a default value in the constructor which controls that behavior.

Comment: In general if you only need read or write access you may (should) use `ifstream`/`ofstream` to make it extra clear.

Comment: Yes but you won't be able to update an already existing file which is the point of 01d55 I think... If you open the file as ofstream or fstream with a ios::out flag it will clear all existing content inside the file, to update a file you need fstream without ios::out. Thanks for the replies ;)

Comment: actually you need both flags like: ios::in|ios::out if you also have the binary flag set...

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ofstream os("example.txt");
    os<<"This is an apple.";
    os.seekp(9);
    os<<" sam";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should be calling `close` on the stream. It will get automatically called in the destructor of `os`, but by that time if there is an exception it will be swallowed.

Comment: @K-ballo: Sure, there's no error check whatsoever in this code, but I'm just following the original example. And, anyway, I don't get your point: a stream object by itself doesn't throw unless you explicitly enable exceptions for it; and, even if it did (let's say an `std::bad_alloc` from an internal buffer), in this sample code there's no `try` block, so even if I called `close()` the exception would just go unhandled and results in `terminate()` being called (which is what would happen here anyway)... or am I missing something else?

Comment: Nope, just thought it was worth mentioning that there is an equivalent to `fclose` as well and that it does not always mean the same than letting the destructor do it for you.

Comment: Uh, ok, although usually I prefer to avoid `close` and instead restrict the scope of file stream objects to exactly the portion of code that needs them to exist (a bit like the `using` statement in C#).

Comment: Also, there are no guarantees that `terminate()` will be called since there are no `try-catch` blocks at all.

Comment: @K-ballo: no, `terminate()` should be called, as for §15.3 ¶9; however, the point that I always forget is that in such case it's implementation-defined if the stack is unwound. So, in a real program, you would have a top-level `try`...`catch` block to assure the stack is unwound up to that point.